# Truncated incorrect date value for concated dates used with IN clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I get the error

```
Warning: #1292 Incorrect datetime value: ''2021-04-01 00:00:00','2021-03-26 00:00:00','2021-03-10 00:00:00','2021-01-08 00:00:00','2020-10-09 00:00:00','2020-04-09 00:...'
```

while using the following SQL

```
SELECT * FROM MF_NAVs WHERE SchemeCode=120503 AND Date IN (
SELECT
    CONCAT(
        "'",
        CONCAT_WS("','",
            MAX(7Day),
            MAX(15Day),
            MAX(1MONTH),
            MAX(3MONTH),
            MAX(6MONTH),
            MAX(1YEAR),
            MAX(3YEAR),
            MAX(5YEAR)
        )
        ,"'") AS Dates
FROM
(
    SELECT 
    CASE WHEN `Date` <= now()- INTERVAL 7 DAY THEN TIMESTAMP(Date,'00:00:00') END AS 7Day,
    CASE WHEN `Date` <= now()- INTERVAL 15 DAY THEN TIMESTAMP(Date,'00:00:00') END AS 15Day,
    CASE WHEN `Date` <= now()- INTERVAL 1 MONTH THEN TIMESTAMP(Date,'00:00:00') END AS 1MONTH,
    CASE WHEN `Date` <= now()- INTERVAL 3 MONTH THEN TIMESTAMP(Date,'00:00:00') END AS 3MONTH,
    CASE WHEN `Date` <= now()- INTERVAL 6 MONTH THEN TIMESTAMP(Date,'00:00:00') END AS 6MONTH,
    CASE WHEN `Date` <= now()- INTERVAL 1 YEAR THEN TIMESTAMP(Date,'00:00:00') END AS 1YEAR,
    CASE WHEN `Date` <= now()- INTERVAL 3 YEAR THEN TIMESTAMP(Date,'00:00:00') END AS 3YEAR,
    CASE WHEN `Date` <= now()- INTERVAL 5 YEAR THEN TIMESTAMP(Date,'00:00:00') END AS 5YEAR
    FROM MF_NAVs
    WHERE SchemeCode=120503
    ORDER BY Date DESC
) AS X
)
```

The subquery returns the following correct dates :

```
'2021-04-01 00:00:00','2021-03-26 00:00:00','2021-03-10 00:00:00','2021-01-08 00:00:00','2020-10-09 00:00:00','2020-04-09 00:00:00','2018-04-10 00:00:00','2016-04-08 00:00:00'
```

How do i fix the error?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do.  I'm guessing there is a simpler construct.]

Comment: From mf_navs table I need all columns but only for 7 days ago, 15 days ago, 1 month ago, 1 year, 3 year and 5 year ago.

Comment: Assuming that `MF_NAVs.Date` is a date and not some string with date representations, there's no need for that `group_concat()`. And an `ORDER BY` in a derived table is pointless unless used with `LIMIT`.

Comment: What is the data type of Date? And what is the purpose of TIMESTAMP(Date,'00:00:00')?

Comment: @stickybit Data type of Date is date, without the concats I get the following error - #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: @forpas - data type of Date is date

Comment: @forpas TimeStamp is *may* be not required, I had added it just to test if that was the issue.

Comment: @bluenile: Yeah, you need to select the values in a single column but not concatenated together. See Bill Karwin's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the operator `IN` only if you have a list of values inside the parentheses.
But you have constructed a string which is a comma separated list of dates.
I think that you can simplify your code with conditional aggregation and the use of `FIND_IN_SET()`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MF_NAVs 
WHERE SchemeCode=120503 
AND FIND_IN_SET(
      Date, 
      (
       SELECT 
         CONCAT_WS( ',',
           MAX(CASE WHEN Date <= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY THEN Date END),
           MAX(CASE WHEN Date <= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 15 DAY THEN Date END),
           MAX(CASE WHEN Date <= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH THEN Date END),
           MAX(CASE WHEN Date <= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 MONTH THEN Date END),
           MAX(CASE WHEN Date <= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 6 MONTH THEN Date END),
           MAX(CASE WHEN Date <= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 YEAR THEN Date END),
           MAX(CASE WHEN Date <= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 YEAR THEN Date END),
           MAX(CASE WHEN Date <= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 5 YEAR THEN Date END)
         )
       FROM MF_NAVs
       WHERE SchemeCode=120503
      ) 
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

First let's talk about the nature of the problem, which is that you're comparing a string to a date.

The `IN()` predicate needs a list of discrete values. You have given it one string value that happens to contain commas.

Think about the difference between these two predicates:

```
WHERE mycolumn IN ('A','B','C')

WHERE mycolumn IN ('A,B,C')
```

The first example above is three quoted values. The second is one quoted value that happens to contain commas.

When in the code in your question, you show:

```
SELECT * FROM MF_NAVs WHERE SchemeCode=120503 AND Date IN ( ...subquery... )
```

But the subquery returns one string (that is, one column & one row). A subquery inside an `IN()` predicate must return multiple values as multiple rows.